# Draw vertical text using MFC

Tags: mfc, drawing, gdi

I am trying to write some vertical text using MFC GDI and somehow the written image clips out when I try to rotate it through an angle (say 30 degrees). Could anyone suggest me as to what might be the problem. The CreateFont definitions and the text to be written is given below:

```
m_SmallFontVert.CreateFont(14,0,300,300,FW_BOLD, FALSE, FALSE, 0, ANSI_CHARSET,
                    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                    DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_ROMAN,
                    "Arial");
```

And my Text:

```
CRect HeightRect(450,850,800,1000);
    HeightRect.MoveToXY(450,500);
    CString HeightText = "HEIGHT";
    pDC->DrawText(HeightText,HeightRect,DT_LEFT);
```

It gives the output:

[image]

Any suggestions on where I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using your DrawText Function, make sure you specify DT_NOCLIP as your format parameter as well so that it doesn't clip your output.

Reference:  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6x7y2a4.aspx)

Something like this:

```
pDC->DrawText(HeightText,HeightRect,DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I used this set of code to get Vertical display of my text.

```
CFont verFont;
verFont.CreateFont(20,10,900,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,0,ARABIC_CHARSET,OUT_TT_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_ROMAN,_T("Tahoma"))

CFont *OFont =(CFont *)pMemDC->SelectObject(&verFont);
pMemDC->TextOut(70,100,"VERTICAL");
```

Then i get the vertical display of that text.
May be this helps you.